# Practicality of using React + Cypress in CI/CD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, continuous-integration, cypress, cicd

I've written some E2E tests in cypress for a react application.

My team plans to put these tests in the CI/CD pipeline. The problem is, that the react app checks the login on every URL visit, logs in, and then continues with the E2E test.

1. In every "it" test, I visit the URL and have a wait of 1000ms implemented to let the page load properly. The problem is, that there are a lot of tests that make this testing really slow. One complete test group takes around 4000-5000ms and there would be more than 10-20 test groups. This would become really slow during the CI/CD.
2. Another problem is, that a lot of these tests implement the typing using the .type() function. It is really slow when we use this. Is there any workaround for this?
3. The last problem that I notice sometimes even when the elements have been rendered, the tests sometimes fail saying that the element was not found or was detached from the DOM, but when looking at the web page at that moment, I can clearly see the element. And re-running the tests, it passes. It becomes very uncertain and these tests also fail sometimes in the headless mode (which will be used in CI/CD I assume). Any comments on this?

Any suggestions/opinions on cypress + react in CI/CD?

Answer (score 0):

to run the tests faster - use: (it can help to solve problem #2)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-parallel